# Rename opened workbook without firstly close it?

Tags: excel, vba

If I want to rename an opened workbook, I need to close it firstly, and then rename it which is a little tedious. 
on 3rd party software “Office Tab” , It has this feature to `Rename opened workbook without firstly close it`.
Is it possible to be done by Excel without using other software ,even by using VBA soultion. 
In advance , greatful for any help.

Comment: You could Save As with the new name, then delete the old-name file in the background?

Comment: Why using `SaveAs` followed by previous workbook deletion is not good enough for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Rename an Open Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RenameMe()
    
    Const ibPrompt As String = "Enter a new file name"
    Const ibTitle As String = "Rename Me"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim DotPosition As Long: DotPosition = InStr(1, wb.Name, ".")
    If DotPosition = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ibDefault As String: ibDefault = Left(wb.Name, DotPosition - 1)
    
    Dim NewBaseName As String
    NewBaseName = InputBox(ibPrompt, ibTitle, ibDefault)
    If Len(NewBaseName) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = wb.FullName
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = wb.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    Dim Extension As String: Extension = Right(Extension, DotPosition)
    
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        wb.SaveAs FolderPath & NewBaseName & Extension
        ErrNum = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ErrNum = 0 Then
        Kill FilePath
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not rename.", vbCritical, "Rename Me"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I faced this issue if new name equal to old name , supposing I have file with name 123.xlsb on desktop and renamed also to 123.xlsb, I got this message
`A file named 'C:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\123.xlsb' already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?`
If I clicked on **Yes** button , I got this `Run-time error '70': Permission denied` on this line of code `Kill FilePath`.
Is it possible to append string `copy` to end of file name is that case. Kindly advice , If I need to post a new question?

Comment: The error is occurring because you have the file open. The easiest way is to put the line `Kill FilePath` between the lines of `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`. If you don't want the message to appear, you can put the `SaveAs` line between the lines `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` which will overwrite (without confirmation). For other options, ask a new question, please.

Answer (score 1):

there are various solutions to this problem,

the first one will be to run the following:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "MyFile.xls"
Kill "MyPreviousFileName.xls"
```

you do have to save it in order to change its name. and if you want to save the old copy, you can remove the `kill` function

if you want it to be more precise you can do as follows (edit: added [@funthomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599798/funthomas)'s suggestion):

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim rootDir as string
Dim FileName as String

rootDir = "\Desktop"
rootDir  = Replace(rootDir, "@1", environ(UserProfile))

FileName = "Test"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs rootDir & FileName & ".xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that there are cases where the Home-Folder is not on C: or the folder name is not equal to the user name. It's better to use `environ(UserProfile) & "\Desktop"`. Even this is not 100% save, but fits almost always.

Comment: Ill add it to my answer! I just copied what i used to check this on my computer