# Rename opened workbook with incremental number without firstly closing it?

Tags: excel, vba

Regarding this question  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108363/rename-opened-workbook-without-firstly-close-it) to rename opened workbook without firstly close it.
The provided answer works greatly ,But I faced cases if new name equal to old name or there is a file with same new name on same folder path. 
I modified the code a bit ( as new name will be picked up without user intervention) and added function to check if a file with new name exists or not before rename. 
I could not manage to add the incremental number ( added “New” instead). 
Now, the code works properly only on first run: 
e.g. **file name** `Plan 12-Mar` changed to  `Plan 12-Mar New` and `Plan 12-Mar` deleted , then I closed it. 
On second run on the renamed file (Plan 12-Mar New) I got the following message:
`file named 'C:\Users\Waleed\Desktop\Plan 12-Mar New.xlsb' already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?` 
If I clicked on Yes button , I got this `Run-time error '70': Permission denied` on this line of code `Kill FilePath`
**Conclusion** if I used the code today , if initial name is “Plan 12-Mar” ,then expected actions are (1) save as with rename to “Plan 12-Mar v2”  (2) delete the old file “Plan 12-Mar” 
and if also I used again today, then expected actions are (1) save as with rename to “Plan 12-Mar v3”  (2) delete the old file “Plan 12-Mar v2”. 
If I used the code tomorrow, then expected actions are (1) save as with rename to “Plan 13-Mar”  (2) delete the old file “Plan 12-Mar v3” , and so on.
Appreciate for yours comments and answers.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Rename_Me()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim DotPosition As Long: DotPosition = InStr(1, wb.Name, ".")
    If DotPosition = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ibDefault As String: ibDefault = Left(wb.Name, DotPosition - 1)
    
    Dim NewBaseName As String
    NewBaseName = "Plan " & Format(Date, "DD-MMM")
    If Len(NewBaseName) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = wb.FullName
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = wb.path & Application.PathSeparator
    Dim Extension As String: Extension = Right(Extension, DotPosition)
    
    Dim ErrNum As Long
     On Error Resume Next
      If Not Is_File_Exists(wb.FullName) Then
         wb.SaveAs FolderPath & NewBaseName & Extension
         ErrNum = Err.Number
      Else
         wb.SaveAs FolderPath & NewBaseName & " New" & Extension  'Instead of "New" ,I v2 ,v3,...
         ErrNum = Err.Number
      End If
     On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ErrNum = 0 Then
        Kill FilePath
    Else
        Kill FilePath
        MsgBox "Could not rename.", vbCritical, "Rename Me"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

And this the function

```
Function Is_File_Exists(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
 'Returns TRUE if the provided name points to an existing file,
 'FALSE if not existing or it's a folder
    On Error Resume Next
    Is_File_Exists = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allocate a new name, based on the algorithm you try explaining, please use the next function:

```
Function NewName(strExisting As String) As String
    Dim boolToday As Boolean, arrSuffix, arrName, nrSuffix As Long
    arrName = Split(strExisting, "."): strExisting = arrName(0)
    'check if the root name refers to today date:
    If InStr(strExisting, "Plan " & Format(Date, "DD-MMM")) > 0 Then boolToday = True
    If boolToday Then
        If IsNumeric(Right(strExisting, 1)) Then
            arrSuffix = Split(strExisting, " V"): nrSuffix = CLng(arrSuffix(1)) + 1
            NewName = arrSuffix(0) & " V" & nrSuffix & "." & arrName(1): Exit Function
        Else
            NewName = strExisting & " V1." & arrName(1): Exit Function
        End If
    Else
        NewName = "Plan " & Format(Date, "DD-MMM") & "." & arrName(1): Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

It will add a suffix incrementing the existing number after "V", **in case of the name containing current day reference** and a new name containing the current date, if a previous one. Then you can delete the workbook with the name sent to the function. It can be tested using the next sub:

```
Sub testNewName()
   Static name As String
   If name = "" Then name = "Plan 11-Mar.xlsb"
   name = NewName(name): Debug.Print name
End Sub
```

Run the sub form some times and see the result in `Immediate Window`.

If, from unknow reasons, a full name identic to the built one can exist, the full name can be checked for its existence and send a message about that before saving As.

Comment: First, I am glad for your comeback , **renaming** works as expected on `Immediate Window` and also works on my main code ,
**But** I could not use your function to delete the old file. I used this from my code and it works ` Kill FilePath`

Comment: @Waleed The above function only does what its name suggests. It assures that the built name follows the logic you required. So, the initial file can be deleted/killed as in your code. Last week I was in a small vacation in Turkey (Antalya) and very seldom had access to internet...

Comment: I was had issue with your answer and was hesitant to message you because of (your last replay)
I test your answer as it is with my full code ,there is an issue to delete the original file after rename.
Why this line `If name = "" Then name = "Plan 11-Mar.xlsb"` it’s better to be **name = ThisWorkbook.name**
also there is no need at all to add `NewName = **** & "." & arrName(1)` on the last line of function as it will cause another issue
if the original name additional contains dot (.) other than dot of extension.

Comment: @Waleed  `If name = "" Then name = "Plan 11-Mar.xlsb"` makes part from a testing sub. **It needs an initial name to be processed after**. It is a simple testing `Sub`! I used it for myself, to test the function and I thought it may be useful for you, too. To be able to check the function before using it in your application. If you do not need that way, feel free to adapt it as you want, or even eliminate it. If your names may contain dots, **you should state about that**. In such a situation I would replace `arrName(1)` with `arrName(Ubound(arrName))`. Don't you need the file extension?